# Using tensorflow and TFBertForNextSentencePrediction to further train bert on a specific corpus

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to train `TFBertForNextSentencePrediction` on my own corpus, not from scratch, but rather taking the existing bert model with only a next sentence prediction head and further train it on a specific cuprous of text (pairs of sentences). Then I want to use the model I trained to be able to extract sentence embeddings from the last hidden state for other texts.

Currently the problem I encounter is that after I train the `keras` model I am not able to extract the hidden states of the last layer before the next sentence prediction head.

Below is the code. Here I only train it on a few sentences just to make sure the code works.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ayala

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from transformers import BertTokenizer, PreTrainedTokenizer, BertConfig, TFBertForNextSentencePrediction
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score


PRETRAINED_MODEL = 'bert-base-uncased'

# set paths and file names
time_stamp = str(datetime.now().year) + "_" + str(datetime.now().month) + "_" + str(datetime.now().day) + "_" + \
                     str(datetime.now().hour) + "_" + str(datetime.now().minute)
model_name = "pretrained_nsp_model"
model_dir_data = model_name + "_" + time_stamp
model_fn = model_dir_data + ".h5"
base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
input_path = os.path.join(base_path, "input_data")
output_path = os.path.join(base_path, "output_models")
model_path = os.path.join(output_path, model_dir_data)
if not os.path.exists(model_path):
    os.makedirs(model_path)

# set model checkpoint
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(model_path, model_fn), monitor="val_loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=True, mode="min")

# read data
max_length = 512

def get_tokenizer(pretrained_model_name):
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name)
    return tokenizer

def tokenize_nsp_data(A, B, max_length):
    data_inputs = tokenizer(A, B, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=max_length, truncation=True,
                             pad_to_max_length=True, return_attention_mask=True,
                             return_tensors="tf")
    return data_inputs

def get_data_features(data_inputs, max_length):
    data_features = {}
    for key in data_inputs:
        data_features[key] = sequence.pad_sequences(data_inputs[key], maxlen=max_length, truncating="post",
                                                          padding="post", value=0)
    return data_features

def get_transformer_model(transformer_model_name):
    # get transformer model
    config = BertConfig(output_attentions=True)
    config.output_hidden_states = True
    config.return_dict = True
    transformer_model = TFBertForNextSentencePrediction.from_pretrained(transformer_model_name, config=config)
    return transformer_model

def get_keras_model(transformer_model):
    # get keras model
    input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,), name='input_ids', dtype='int32')
    input_masks_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,), name='attention_mask', dtype='int32')
    token_type_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_length,), name='token_type_ids', dtype='int32')
    X = transformer_model({'input_ids': input_ids, 'attention_mask': input_masks_ids, 'token_type_ids': token_type_ids})[0]
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, input_masks_ids, token_type_ids], outputs=X)
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00005), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def get_metrices(true_values, pred_values):
    cm = confusion_matrix(true_values, pred_values)
    acc_score = accuracy_score(true_values, pred_values)
    f1 = f1_score(true_values, pred_values, average="binary")
    precision = precision_score(true_values, pred_values, average="binary")
    recall = recall_score(true_values, pred_values, average="binary")
    metrices = {'confusion_matrix': cm,
                'acc_score': acc_score,
                'f1': f1,
                'precision': precision,
                'recall': recall
                }
    for k, v in metrices.items():
        print(k, ':\n', v)
    return metrices

# get tokenizer
tokenizer = get_tokenizer(PRETRAINED_MODEL)

# train 
prompt = ["Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"]
next_sentence = ["How are you?", "Pizza", "How are you?", "Pizza"]
train_labels = [0, 1, 0, 1]
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
train_inputs = tokenize_nsp_data(prompt, next_sentence, max_length)
train_data_features = get_data_features(train_inputs, max_length)

# val
prompt = ["Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"]
next_sentence = ["How are you?", "Pizza", "How are you?", "Pizza"]
val_labels = [0, 1, 0, 1]
val_labels = to_categorical(val_labels)
val_inputs = tokenize_nsp_data(prompt, next_sentence, max_length)
val_data_features = get_data_features(val_inputs, max_length)

# get transformer model
transformer_model = get_transformer_model(PRETRAINED_MODEL)

# get keras model
model = get_keras_model(transformer_model)

callback_list = []
early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, min_delta=0.005, verbose=1)
callback_list.append(early_stop)
reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=2, epsilon=0.001)
callback_list.append(reduce_lr)
callback_list.append(checkpoint)

history = model.fit([train_data_features['input_ids'], train_data_features['attention_mask'],
                     train_data_features['token_type_ids']], np.array(train_labels), batch_size=2, epochs=3,
                    validation_data=([val_data_features['input_ids'], val_data_features['attention_mask'],
                                      val_data_features['token_type_ids']], np.array(val_labels)), verbose=1,
                    callbacks=callback_list)

model.layers[3].save_pretrained(model_path)  # need to save this and make sure i can get the hidden states

##  predict
# load model
transformer_model = get_transformer_model(model_path)
model = get_keras_model(transformer_model)
model.summary()
model.load_weights(os.path.join(model_path, model_fn))


# test
prompt = ["Hello", "Hello"]
next_sentence = ["How are you?", "Pizza"]
test_labels = [0, 1]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': prompt, 'B': next_sentence, 'label': test_labels})
test_labels = to_categorical(val_labels)
test_inputs = tokenize_nsp_data(prompt, next_sentence, max_length)
test_data_features = get_data_features(test_inputs, max_length)

# predict
pred_test = model.predict([test_data_features['input_ids'], test_data_features['attention_mask'], test_data_features['token_type_ids']])
preds = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tf.convert_to_tensor(pred_test)).numpy()

true_test = test_df['label'].to_list()
pred_test = [1 if p[1] > 0.5 else 0 for p in preds]
test_df['pred_val'] = pred_test

metrices = get_metrices(true_test, pred_test)
```

I am also attaching a picture from the debugging mode in which I try (with no success) to view the hidden state. **The problem is I am not able to see and save the transform model I trained and view the embeddings of the last hidden state.** I tried converting the `KerasTensor` to `numpy array` but without success.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue resides in your 'get_keras_model()' function. You defined here that you are only interested in the first of the element of the output (i.e. logits) with:

```py
X = transformer_model({'input_ids': input_ids, 'attention_mask': input_masks_ids, 'token_type_ids': token_type_ids})[0]
```

Just do the index selection as conditional like this to get the whole output of the model

```py
def get_keras_model(transformer_model, is_training=True):
    ###your other code
    X = transformer_model({'input_ids': input_ids, 'attention_mask': input_masks_ids, 'token_type_ids': token_type_ids})
    if is_training:
        X= X[0]

    ###your other code
    return model

#predict
###your other code
model = get_keras_model(transformer_model, is_training=False)
###your other code
print(pred_test.keys())
```

Output:

```py
odict_keys(['logits', 'hidden_states', 'attentions'])
```

P.S.: The BertTokenizer can truncate and add padding by themself ([documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__)).

Comment: Thanks @cronoik. When I try your suggestion I get an error `ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((2, 12, 512, 512) vs (2, 2))`. I tried what you suggested before uploading my question but I couldn't solve this error. Were you able to run the whole code following the what you suggested in the answer?

Comment: @ayalaall No, I did not. I only executed the parts that were relevant to answer your question. You can fix that error  by correcting the line: `preds = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tf.convert_to_tensor(pred_test)).numpy()
` to `preds = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tf.convert_to_tensor(pred_test.logits)).numpy()
`.

Comment: The error I described occurs when I fit the model (please see below), not when I try to get the predictions
`history = model.fit([train_data_features['input_ids'], train_data_features['attention_mask'],
                     train_data_features['token_type_ids']], np.array(train_labels), batch_size=2, epochs=3,
                    validation_data=([val_data_features['input_ids'], val_data_features['attention_mask'],
                                      val_data_features['token_type_ids']], np.array(val_labels)), verbose=1,
                    callbacks=callback_list)`

Comment: Yes. Just to be sure I copied and pasted the code from my question here to a new script, then changed the two lines of code according to your suggestions (the one in `get_keras_model()` and when I get `preds`) and I still get the error in `model.fit()` 
    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((2, 12, 512, 512) vs (2, 2))

Comment: Sure. Posted the edited question now. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct @cromoik. I indeed didn't apply all the changes you suggested. After doing so everything works. Thanks very much for the help. I learned a lot from this!

Comment: @ayalaall No problem let us just clean up the comments.

Comment: Hi  @cronoik. I have a question regarding the `X= X[0]`. I read a few blog posts and notice some have this part and some don't. In which situations would I like to include this part doing fine-tune of the model? My goal is to fine-tune the `TFBertForNextSentencePrediction` pre-trained model on my own corpus and to unfreeze some of the top transformer layers and not fine-tune only the NSP head. Should I use the`X= X[0]` for this? Then, I'd like to use the fine-tuned transformer part of the model without the NSP head, and put another classification head on top of it and further fine tune it. Tnx